# Differences between View Holder Pattern and Custom Views in ListView

Tags: android, listview

To avoid expensive extra calls to `findViewById`, the View Holder pattern is advised for rows in a ListView. What are the reasons for choosing this approach over a custom View class? Are there restrictions or is there a performance impact to consider for custom Views within a ListView?

To phrase this another way, can the View Holder role be filled by a custom View class which is instantiated and returned from the ArrayAdapter's `getView` method? It would be storing references to its own Views internally, which could be updated indirectly through methods defined on this custom View's class.

I have looked for answers on this specific topic, without much success. If I have overlooked this same question elsewhere, do let me know.

Comment: did you read the documentation that talks about the ViewHolder's pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some prefer to have a custom compound view over a view holder.
You have more flexibility with the custom view (could implement your own viewgroup to simplify the measure/layout passes).
ViewHolder is usually easier to implement.

Here is a good article on it: http://blog.xebia.com/2013/07/22/viewholder-considered-harmful/